# Addition of Covariate Matrices in Multi Normal Gaussian Addition

Tags: variance, covariance-matrix

I want to merge two different distance functions for one set of observations $(x, y)$ to use in a gaussian process regression. I have the covariance matrix $\Sigma_1$ from distance function number 1 and covariance matrix $\Sigma_2$ can i write
$$Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2) $$

or do i need some sort of weighting or is variance not additive.
thanks

Comment: Check out section 4.2.4 of Rasmussen and Williams for general info on combining kernel functions http://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf